# Regular Expression javascript for cip code

Tags: javascript, regex

I need this regular expression for this format

> (##.####)

I think it should be something like this

```
/[0-9]*[.][0-9]/
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: What regular expression did you try and that did not work?

Comment: I dont have any strong idea. i think i should be like this  /[0-9]*[.][0-9]/

Comment: @fnkr: Note the tag JavaScript...

Comment: @fnkr: `XRegExp` is a lib, not the native JS `RegExp` constructor. Besides, for something this easy, there really isn't a need to overcomplicate things IMO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll bite. This should work:

```
var re = /(^\d{2}\.\d{4}$)/;
```

```
(^    - begin
\d{2} - match two digits
\.    - the period between digit sets
\d{4} - match four digits
$)    - end
```

And if you need the parantheses:

```
var re = /(^\(\d{2}\.\d{4}\)$)/;
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WG5M2/)

Answer (score 0):

I assume, that the brackets does not belong to the pattern.

Use the [quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `{x}` where `x` is the number of repetitions you want to find. With `\d` you can match a digit.

The next important point is, you need to anchor your regex to avoid getting partial matches:

1. You want to find the word within a longer string

   use the [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b` to ensure that there is no other [word character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#shorthand) before and after your pattern.

   ```
   /\b\d{2}\.\d{4}\b/
   ```
2. The complete string should fit that pattern

   Use the [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` and `$` to match the start and the end of the string.

   ```
   /^\d{2}\.\d{4}$/
   ```